# Using the linprog function in Matlab for mathematical optimization problems

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I would like to use the `linprog` function from Matlab to solve this mathematical model. Can you help me with this? I know we need to use something like `linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)`. If you need more information, please just let us know.

`f`: the objective function coefficients

`A`: the matrix of inequality constraint coefficients

`b`: the vector of inequality constraint values

`Aeq`: the matrix of equality constraint coefficients

`beq`: the vector of equality constraint values

`lb`: the lower bounds on the decision variables

`ub`: the upper bounds on the decision variables

**Parameters:**

```
n = 3; 
m = 4; 
J = 5;
Pi = [1000; 1500; 2000]
Lk = [2000; 2500; 3000; 3500];
Cik = [3 4 5 6; 2 3 4 5; 4 5 6 7]; % 
Ckj = [5 6 7 8; 4 5 6 7; 6 7 8 9; 3 4 5 6; 2 3 4 5]; 
CAk = [1000; 1500; 2000; 2500]; 
CIk = [5000; 6000; 7000; 8000]:
Nj = [1500; 2000; 2500; 3000; 3500]; 
alpha = 0.8
```

**Variables:**

```
X_k={1, if location x is chosen for installation of the processing center,
     0, otherwise

Y_ik=quantity of sludge from wastewater treatment plant i that will be transported to location k

Z_kj=quantity of biofertilizer sent to location k for farm j
```

**Objetive function:**

[image]

**Restrictions:**

[image]

First, the idea is to pass the objective function and constraints to Matlab format so that you can extract the information to use the `linprog` function. So my objective function looks like this:

```
obj = sum(sum(Cik .* Y .* X)) + sum((CI + CA) .* X) + sum(sum(Ckj .* Z .* X));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Reinderien, what I did was pass the objective function in matlab format. I'll insert it in the question for you to see. However, I need to pass the constraints to the Matlab format as well, but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: Your objective and some of your constraints are nonlinear and cannot be expressed directly in a MILP problem without modification. Do you know how to linearize dot products of binary variables?

Comment: Unfortunately not, can you help me? I'm still new to this subject, so I was just told to use `linprog`, so I'm trying to solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, there are two major issues with your LP problem:

### Non-linearity

The problem is not linear. You're multiplying two variables in multiple places. You need to linearise, which in this case means:

- Do not represent Y and Z independently of X. Instead, only operate on the implicit products XkYki and XkZkj.
- Add additional constraints for XY and XZ, of the form

```
    XY <= buffer*X
    XZ <= buffer*X
```

The buffer is some value larger than the maximum magnitude of Y and Z respectively.

### Infeasibility

For your current values, there is no solution. If all values are held as fixed except `alpha`, then for a feasible solution, `alpha > 2.7`.

### Example implementation

This uses Python and PuLP. I leave conversion to Matlab as an exercise for the reader.

```py
import numpy as np
import pulp


Pi = np.array((1000, 1500, 2000))
Lk = np.array((2000, 2500, 3000, 3500))
Cik = np.array((
    (3, 4, 5, 6),
    (2, 3, 4, 5),
    (4, 5, 6, 7),
))
Ckj = np.array((
    (5, 6, 7, 8),
    (4, 5, 6, 7),
    (6, 7, 8, 9),
    (3, 4, 5, 6),
    (2, 3, 4, 5),
)).T
CAk = np.array((1000, 1500, 2000, 2500))
CIk = np.array((5000, 6000, 7000, 8000))
Nj = np.array((1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500))
alpha = 3  # 0.8 is infeasible, as is anything < 2.78
n, m = Cik.shape
m, J = Ckj.shape

Xk = [
    pulp.LpVariable(name=f'X({k})', cat=pulp.LpBinary)  # (9)
    for k in range(m)
]
XYki = [
    [
        pulp.LpVariable(name=f'XY({k},{i})', lowBound=0)  # (10)
        for i in range(n)
    ] for k in range(m)
]
XZkj = [
    [
        pulp.LpVariable(name=f'XZ({k},{j})', lowBound=0)  # (11)
        for j in range(J)
    ] for k in range(m)
]

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='sludge_processing', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

prob.objective = pulp.lpSum(
    CIk[k]*pulp.lpSum(XYki[k])
    + (CIk[k] + CAk[k])*Xk[k]
    + pulp.lpDot(Ckj[k], XZkj[k])
    for k in range(m)
)

'''
Products of Xk are non-linear and cannot be expressed directly
If Xk==0, XYki==0 and XZki==0

0 <= XY <= buffer_y*X   buffer_y >> max(P, L)
0 <= XZ <= buffer_z*X   buffer_z >> max(N)
'''
buffer_y = 10*max(Pi.max(), Lk.max())
buffer_z = 10*Nj.max()
for k in range(m):
    for i in range(n):
        prob.addConstraint(name=f'Ylin({k},{i})', constraint=XYki[k][i] <= buffer_y*Xk[k])
    for j in range(J):
        prob.addConstraint(name=f'Zlin({k},{j})', constraint=XZkj[k][j] <= buffer_z*Xk[k])

for i in range(n):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'Constr_5({i})',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(XYki[k][i] for k in range(m)) <= Pi[i],
    )
for k in range(m):
    prob.addConstraint(name=f'Constr_6({k})', constraint=pulp.lpSum(XYki[k]) <= Lk[k])
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'Constr_7({k})',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(XZkj[k]) <= alpha*pulp.lpSum(XYki[k]),
    )
for j in range(J):
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'Constr_8({j})',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(XZkj[k][j] for k in range(m)) >= Nj[j],
    )


print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

Xk = np.array([x.value() for x in Xk])
print('Xk =', Xk)

XYki = np.array([
    [xy.value() for xy in XYi]
    for XYi in XYki
])
print('XYki =')
print(XYki)

XZkj = np.array([
    [xz.value() for xz in XZj]
    for XZj in XZkj
])
print('XZkj =')
print(XZkj)
print()

print('(5):', XYki.sum(axis=0), '<=', Pi)
print('(6):', XYki.sum(axis=1), '<=', Lk)
print('(7):', XZkj.sum(axis=1), '<=', alpha*XYki.sum(axis=1))
print('(8):', XZkj.sum(axis=0), '>=', Nj)
```

```
sludge_processing:
MINIMIZE
6000*X(0) + 7500*X(1) + 9000*X(2) + 10500*X(3) + 5000*XY(0,0) + 5000*XY(0,1) + 5000*XY(0,2) + 6000*XY(1,0) + 6000*XY(1,1) + 6000*XY(1,2) + 7000*XY(2,0) + 7000*XY(2,1) + 7000*XY(2,2) + 8000*XY(3,0) + 8000*XY(3,1) + 8000*XY(3,2) + 5*XZ(0,0) + 4*XZ(0,1) + 6*XZ(0,2) + 3*XZ(0,3) + 2*XZ(0,4) + 6*XZ(1,0) + 5*XZ(1,1) + 7*XZ(1,2) + 4*XZ(1,3) + 3*XZ(1,4) + 7*XZ(2,0) + 6*XZ(2,1) + 8*XZ(2,2) + 5*XZ(2,3) + 4*XZ(2,4) + 8*XZ(3,0) + 7*XZ(3,1) + 9*XZ(3,2) + 6*XZ(3,3) + 5*XZ(3,4) + 0
SUBJECT TO
Ylin(0,0): - 35000 X(0) + XY(0,0) <= 0

Ylin(0,1): - 35000 X(0) + XY(0,1) <= 0

Ylin(0,2): - 35000 X(0) + XY(0,2) <= 0

Zlin(0,0): - 35000 X(0) + XZ(0,0) <= 0

Zlin(0,1): - 35000 X(0) + XZ(0,1) <= 0

Zlin(0,2): - 35000 X(0) + XZ(0,2) <= 0

Zlin(0,3): - 35000 X(0) + XZ(0,3) <= 0

Zlin(0,4): - 35000 X(0) + XZ(0,4) <= 0

Ylin(1,0): - 35000 X(1) + XY(1,0) <= 0

Ylin(1,1): - 35000 X(1) + XY(1,1) <= 0

Ylin(1,2): - 35000 X(1) + XY(1,2) <= 0

Zlin(1,0): - 35000 X(1) + XZ(1,0) <= 0

Zlin(1,1): - 35000 X(1) + XZ(1,1) <= 0

Zlin(1,2): - 35000 X(1) + XZ(1,2) <= 0

Zlin(1,3): - 35000 X(1) + XZ(1,3) <= 0

Zlin(1,4): - 35000 X(1) + XZ(1,4) <= 0

Ylin(2,0): - 35000 X(2) + XY(2,0) <= 0

Ylin(2,1): - 35000 X(2) + XY(2,1) <= 0

Ylin(2,2): - 35000 X(2) + XY(2,2) <= 0

Zlin(2,0): - 35000 X(2) + XZ(2,0) <= 0

Zlin(2,1): - 35000 X(2) + XZ(2,1) <= 0

Zlin(2,2): - 35000 X(2) + XZ(2,2) <= 0

Zlin(2,3): - 35000 X(2) + XZ(2,3) <= 0

Zlin(2,4): - 35000 X(2) + XZ(2,4) <= 0

Ylin(3,0): - 35000 X(3) + XY(3,0) <= 0

Ylin(3,1): - 35000 X(3) + XY(3,1) <= 0

Ylin(3,2): - 35000 X(3) + XY(3,2) <= 0

Zlin(3,0): - 35000 X(3) + XZ(3,0) <= 0

Zlin(3,1): - 35000 X(3) + XZ(3,1) <= 0

Zlin(3,2): - 35000 X(3) + XZ(3,2) <= 0

Zlin(3,3): - 35000 X(3) + XZ(3,3) <= 0

Zlin(3,4): - 35000 X(3) + XZ(3,4) <= 0

Constr_5(0): XY(0,0) + XY(1,0) + XY(2,0) + XY(3,0) <= 1000

Constr_5(1): XY(0,1) + XY(1,1) + XY(2,1) + XY(3,1) <= 1500

Constr_5(2): XY(0,2) + XY(1,2) + XY(2,2) + XY(3,2) <= 2000

Constr_6(0): XY(0,0) + XY(0,1) + XY(0,2) <= 2000

Constr_7(0): - 3 XY(0,0) - 3 XY(0,1) - 3 XY(0,2) + XZ(0,0) + XZ(0,1) + XZ(0,2)
 + XZ(0,3) + XZ(0,4) <= 0

Constr_6(1): XY(1,0) + XY(1,1) + XY(1,2) <= 2500

Constr_7(1): - 3 XY(1,0) - 3 XY(1,1) - 3 XY(1,2) + XZ(1,0) + XZ(1,1) + XZ(1,2)
 + XZ(1,3) + XZ(1,4) <= 0

Constr_6(2): XY(2,0) + XY(2,1) + XY(2,2) <= 3000

Constr_7(2): - 3 XY(2,0) - 3 XY(2,1) - 3 XY(2,2) + XZ(2,0) + XZ(2,1) + XZ(2,2)
 + XZ(2,3) + XZ(2,4) <= 0

Constr_6(3): XY(3,0) + XY(3,1) + XY(3,2) <= 3500

Constr_7(3): - 3 XY(3,0) - 3 XY(3,1) - 3 XY(3,2) + XZ(3,0) + XZ(3,1) + XZ(3,2)
 + XZ(3,3) + XZ(3,4) <= 0

Constr_8(0): XZ(0,0) + XZ(1,0) + XZ(2,0) + XZ(3,0) >= 1500

Constr_8(1): XZ(0,1) + XZ(1,1) + XZ(2,1) + XZ(3,1) >= 2000

Constr_8(2): XZ(0,2) + XZ(1,2) + XZ(2,2) + XZ(3,2) >= 2500

Constr_8(3): XZ(0,3) + XZ(1,3) + XZ(2,3) + XZ(3,3) >= 3000

Constr_8(4): XZ(0,4) + XZ(1,4) + XZ(2,4) + XZ(3,4) >= 3500

VARIABLES
0 <= X(0) <= 1 Integer
0 <= X(1) <= 1 Integer
0 <= X(2) <= 1 Integer
0 <= X(3) <= 1 Integer
XY(0,0) Continuous
XY(0,1) Continuous
XY(0,2) Continuous
XY(1,0) Continuous
XY(1,1) Continuous
XY(1,2) Continuous
XY(2,0) Continuous
XY(2,1) Continuous
XY(2,2) Continuous
XY(3,0) Continuous
XY(3,1) Continuous
XY(3,2) Continuous
XZ(0,0) Continuous
XZ(0,1) Continuous
XZ(0,2) Continuous
XZ(0,3) Continuous
XZ(0,4) Continuous
XZ(1,0) Continuous
XZ(1,1) Continuous
XZ(1,2) Continuous
XZ(1,3) Continuous
XZ(1,4) Continuous
XZ(2,0) Continuous
XZ(2,1) Continuous
XZ(2,2) Continuous
XZ(2,3) Continuous
XZ(2,4) Continuous
XZ(3,0) Continuous
XZ(3,1) Continuous
XZ(3,2) Continuous
XZ(3,3) Continuous
XZ(3,4) Continuous

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - .venv\lib\site-packages\pulp\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe Temp\6571454a90aa4266aea2599a389c663e-pulp.mps timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution Temp\6571454a90aa4266aea2599a389c663e-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 53 COLUMNS
At line 238 RHS
At line 287 BOUNDS
At line 292 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 48 rows, 36 columns and 140 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 2.30537e+07 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 24 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 48 rows, 36 columns (4 integer (4 of which binary)) and 144 elements
Cbc0038I Initial state - 1 integers unsatisfied sum - 0.133333
Cbc0038I Solution found of 2.30665e+07
Cbc0038I Relaxing continuous gives 2.30665e+07
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 3 integers at bound fixed and 23 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 48 rows 36 columns, reduced to 5 rows 5 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.02 seconds)
Cbc0038I Round again with cutoff of 2.30664e+07
Cbc0038I Reduced cost fixing fixed 3 variables on major pass 2
Cbc0038I Pass   1: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 1
Cbc0038I Pass   2: suminf.    0.13333 (1) obj. 2.30655e+07 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   3: suminf.    0.13333 (1) obj. 2.30655e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   4: suminf.    0.13333 (1) obj. 2.30655e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   5: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   6: suminf.    0.13333 (1) obj. 2.30655e+07 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   7: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 5
Cbc0038I Pass   8: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass   9: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  10: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  11: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  12: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  13: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  14: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  15: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  16: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  17: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  18: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  19: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  20: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  21: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  22: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  23: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  24: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  25: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  26: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  27: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  28: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  29: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I Pass  30: suminf.    0.01333 (1) obj. 2.30664e+07 iterations 0
Cbc0038I No solution found this major pass
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 3 integers at bound fixed and 23 continuous
Cbc0038I Full problem 48 rows 36 columns, reduced to 5 rows 5 columns
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I After 0.03 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting with objective of 2.30665e+07 - took 0.02 seconds
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 23066500 found by feasibility pump after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.03 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 48 rows 36 columns, reduced to 20 rows 17 columns
Cbc0006I The LP relaxation is infeasible or too expensive
Cbc0013I At root node, 0 cuts changed objective from 23065500 to 23066500 in 1 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 1 column cuts (1 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is 1
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 6 (TwoMirCuts) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 7 (ZeroHalf) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.000 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 23066500, took 1 iterations and 0 nodes (0.05 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 3 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from 2.30655e+07 to 2.30665e+07
Probing was tried 1 times and created 1 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
ZeroHalf was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                23066500.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               1
Time (CPU seconds):             0.06
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.06

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.06   (Wallclock seconds):       0.06

Xk = [1. 1. 0. 0.]
XYki =
[[   0.         0.      2000.     ]
 [ 666.66667 1500.         0.     ]
 [   0.         0.         0.     ]
 [   0.         0.         0.     ]]
XZkj =
[[   0.    0.    0. 2500. 3500.]
 [1500. 2000. 2500.  500.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]

(5): [ 666.66667 1500.      2000.     ] <= [1000 1500 2000]
(6): [2000.      2166.66667    0.         0.     ] <= [2000 2500 3000 3500]
(7): [6000. 6500.    0.    0.] <= [6000.      6500.00001    0.         0.     ]
(8): [1500. 2000. 2500. 3000. 3500.] >= [1500 2000 2500 3000 3500]
```